What does "concerned" mean here?
From John Le Carré's Smiley's People, where Lacon was briefing Smiley:

Three years ago, George—let us start there—soon after you left the Circus—your successor Saul Enderby—your worthy successor—under pressure from a concerned Cabinet —by concerned I mean newly formed—decided on certain far-reaching changes of intelligence practice.

Does that mean worried or related/involved?
p.s. Just saw my question closed and someone said about consulting a dictionary. Want to say something about that.
First I think I already got a good answer to this question so I actually don't mind much about it being closed.
I'd like to say I did look up the word in dictionary. The point is for a word with multiple meanings, sometimes it's not so easy to tell which definition is the right one in a certain context and you will need people's help on that rather than dictionaries.
Don't assume people asking questions here without looking up in a dictionary first.

What's the source and surrounding context?

@alphabet Edited the question. Thank you for your concern!

(For anyone else who's confused: "the Circus" here refers to MI6, not an actual circus.)

Given more context, it seems to mean 'worried'. But of course in politics they will be involved too, but at a distance from the action.

@WeatherVane what puzzles me is that if it means worried, how to explain ‘by concerned I mean newly formed’? It doesn't seem quite logical.

It probably means both. They are involved, and they are worried.

I would guess that the point is that, when a new Cabinet takes over, they decide to suddenly start making changes all over the place; concerned here means something more like "interested" or "engaged."

@alphabet I think what you said makes sense. Please turn your comment into an answer and I will mark it as accepted.

I'd interpret it as the Cabinet being caught between a rock and a hard place. "Concerned" here being a euphemism.

This question should not be closed. It is not a dictionary question, as the OP has explained in the edit. It is a question about understanding the meaning of said word in a particular context.

@alphabet You're right that "the Circus" here refers to MI6. But Circus here does not mean a travelling company of acrobats, but refers to the Cambridge Circus in London where MI6's building is.

The excerpt 'under pressure from a concerned Cabinet —by concerned I mean newly formed' is obviously stretching language. A non-synonymous witticism like 'For 'attractive' read 'loaded'. This is unwise when one of the words has more than one common meaning. However, a dictionary will tell one that prenominal 'concerned' always has the 'worried' sense.


worried or related/involved?

These definitions are not necessarily contradictory. One can be worried and therefore involved, and both may sometimes be implied from concerned.
As @jsw29 has noted in the comments, this phrase is problematic because of I mean newly formed, not concerned. (Or the juxtaposition of those two adjectives with respect to the Cabinet.) Newly formed seems to have no direct bearing on concerned.
—by concerned I mean newly formed—
In this context concerned would mean that since the Cabinet is newly formed, the members are worried, in the sense that they are uncertain, confused and over-zealous about policy and procedure. Lacon appears to be sarcastically insulting the new Cabinet - he doesn't approve of their changes. Concerned here is used typically.

In other words, concerned is used here in pretty much its usual sense (so looking up its entry in a dictionary would not help clarify the meaning of the sentence); if there is anything that makes the sentence difficult to understand, it's that mean is used in it very loosely.

@jsw29 - Yes, that is how it works out. Concerned is used in the usual sense of worried/involved (Not really contradictory meanings.) I mean newly formed makes it problematic, since concerned on its face has nothing to do with newly formed. It is not a dictionary question, but a question of usage and interpretation. (I have edited the answer to include your comment. For some reason there seems to be an an untoward tendency on this site to close many questions as dictionary questions, when they are not all such.)

Passage in Question:

Three years ago, George—let us start there—soon after you left the
Circus—your successor Saul Enderby—your worthy successor—under
pressure from a concerned Cabinet —by concerned I mean newly
formed—decided on certain far-reaching changes of intelligence
practice.

TLDR
In short, there are two possibilities. Briefly:

"Concerned" means: a cabinet that is concerned OR
"Concerned" means: a cabinet that is concerning (to the speaker)**

Wordier TLDR:
Here is possibility #1 first: "concerned" here may be synonymous with problematic--based on the context outside of looking to a dictionary on standard modern English. This would be a non-standard usage of the word "concerned".
Now, on to the second possibility: The second possibility requires the standard usage: "concerned" in the phrase "concerned cabinet" may simply mean that there is a Cabinet that demonstrates concern about some topic or practice.
Literary Analysis for context:
Please read below for a deeper discussion. Here lies a literary analysis that is provided to obtain context for Le Carré's intended usage of the word "concerned":
Without familiarity with Le Carré's Smiley's People or Le Carré's style or time of writing (which may affect popular but non-standardized styles of writing),there are a few points I would address first.
The Context: The character's personality or feelings at the moment: nuanced, complex, choppy, and possibly erratic. Le Carré may mean to draw a character in our mind's canvas as a character whose speech is full of nuance, suggesting that the character's mind, while discussing or mentioning something, contains opinions that the character wishes to ascribe to that something. That something here is the "cabinet". The "cabinet" is the topic of concern. And, those concerns are met with opinions that are expressed in a disorganized manner, signified by the use of em-dashes which show an interruption in the flow of the speech. It may also mean to suggest a personality trait of the character, who may come off as very granular (detailed), and very elaborate--perhaps so elaborate that it would be considered obtuse (similar to how you may feel about me writing this). The character's flow of thoughts is also choppy, which may mean to reflect the character's current internal state of feelings. There is also humor riddled in his choppiness--almost a sarcasm at certain parts. Maybe, the character is nervous. Maybe, the character is chaotic. You may know better based on your reading of the book up to that passage. Taken together, long story short, the character in focused is hyper-detailed, a little chaotic and even possibly flustered. This affects how we may interpret the particular wording.
Now, with the above context, I think I can easily answer your question, which amounts to "What does "concerned" mean here (as it is used in the aforementioned passage in question)?"
So, now, the character first says "concerned cabinet" then, following an interjection of a nested thought that is signified by the em-dash, the character then states, "by concerned I mean newly formed", as if concerned was intended as a jeer/"dis" and he's rephrasing for sarcastic effect.
By "concerned" he means to say "Concerning"--i.e., there is a problematic situation arising. Since the word "concerned" is used as an adjective to modify "cabinet"--he means to say that the specific people who formed the cabinet are a cause for concern. The English is not modern or standard (at least according to my intuition of North American English). This makes sense because this book was written in 1979 but I would expect the language to be of very formal and educated characters--perhaps, even British characters if they are not American.
Thus, the use of the word "concerned" as a less-standard adjectival modifier when modifying the noun "cabinet" here is not intended to indicate that the cabinet is "feeling concerned"; Rather, the author intends that this character is (most likely) concerned about the Cabinet--at a minimum. He may further mean to suggest that the composition of the newly formed cabinet is concerning for more than just him. In other words, there were people put on the cabinet that may not be liked by the character or may be bad picks to be selected for the cabinet.
I hope this helps.

Thank you for providing so much information and even some literacy analysis that is beyond the scope of language.

Prasanth - the characters are certainly British! Le Carré famously wrote novels about the British Secret Service.

Thank you ladies and gentlemen. Not sure why I got a -1. The answer is pretty complete.
